# PHP Search Query with SQLite3 Database

Tags: php, sqlite

I found a very nice search query [here](https://phppot.com/php/advanced-search-using-php/) but this search query uses a `mysql database` and now i am trying to adapt this code into a `SQLite3 database` but with my current code i get this error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchArray() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\xport\searchtext.php on line 79

**Below is my current code**

```
<?php
require_once ("db.php");
$db = new MyDB();

$with_any_one_of = "";
$with_the_exact_of = "";
$without = "";
$starts_with = "";
$search_in = "";
$advance_search_submit = "";

$queryCondition = "";
if(!empty($_POST["search"])) {
    $advance_search_submit = $_POST["advance_search_submit"];
    foreach($_POST["search"] as $k=>$v){
        if(!empty($v)) {

            $queryCases = array("with_any_one_of","with_the_exact_of","without","starts_with");
            if(in_array($k,$queryCases)) {
                if(!empty($queryCondition)) {
                    $queryCondition .= " AND ";
                } else {
                    $queryCondition .= " WHERE ";
                }
            }
            switch($k) {
                case "with_any_one_of":
                    $with_any_one_of = $v;
                    $wordsAry = explode(" ", $v);
                    $wordsCount = count($wordsAry);
                    for($i=0;$i<$wordsCount;$i++) {
                        if(!empty($_POST["search"]["search_in"])) {
                            $queryCondition .= $_POST["search"]["search_in"] . " LIKE '%" . $wordsAry[$i] . "%'";
                        } else {
                            $queryCondition .= "question LIKE '" . $wordsAry[$i] . "%' OR answer LIKE '" . $wordsAry[$i] . "%'";
                        }
                        if($i!=$wordsCount-1) {
                            $queryCondition .= " OR ";
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case "with_the_exact_of":
                    $with_the_exact_of = $v;
                    if(!empty($_POST["search"]["search_in"])) {
                        $queryCondition .= $_POST["search"]["search_in"] . " LIKE '%" . $v . "%'";
                    } else {
                        $queryCondition .= "question LIKE '%" . $v . "%' OR answer LIKE '%" . $v . "%'";
                    }
                    break;
                case "without":
                    $without = $v;
                    if(!empty($_POST["search"]["search_in"])) {
                        $queryCondition .= $_POST["search"]["search_in"] . " NOT LIKE '%" . $v . "%'";
                    } else {
                        $queryCondition .= "question NOT LIKE '%" . $v . "%' AND answer NOT LIKE '%" . $v . "%'";
                    }
                    break;
                case "starts_with":
                    $starts_with = $v;
                    if(!empty($_POST["search"]["search_in"])) {
                        $queryCondition .= $_POST["search"]["search_in"] . " LIKE '" . $v . "%'";
                    } else {
                        $queryCondition .= "question LIKE '" . $v . "%' OR answer LIKE '" . $v . "%'";
                    }
                    break;
                case "search_in":
                    $search_in = $_POST["search"]["search_in"];
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
$orderby = " ORDER BY quiz_id desc"; 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM questions " . $queryCondition;
$result = $db->exec($sql);
if($result)
{
    echo "Good";
    while ($row = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC))
    {
        $question = $row['question'];
        echo $question;
    }
}
else 
{
    echo "No results found";
}
?>
<form name="frmSearch" method="post" action="searchtext.php">
<input type="hidden" id="advance_search_submit" name="advance_search_submit" value="<?php echo $advance_search_submit; ?>">
<div class="search-box">
    <label class="search-label">With Any One of the Words:</label>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="search[with_any_one_of]" class="demoInputBox" value="<?php echo $with_any_one_of; ?>"  />
        <span id="advance_search_link" onClick="showHideAdvanceSearch()">Advance Search</span>
    </div>              
    <div id="advanced-search-box" <?php if(empty($advance_search_submit)) { ?>style="display:none;"<?php } ?>>
        <label class="search-label">With the Exact String:</label>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="search[with_the_exact_of]" id="with_the_exact_of" class="demoInputBox" value="<?php echo $with_the_exact_of; ?>"   />
        </div>
        <label class="search-label">Without:</label>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="search[without]" id="without" class="demoInputBox" value="<?php echo $without; ?>" />
        </div>
        <label class="search-label">Starts With:</label>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="search[starts_with]" id="starts_with" class="demoInputBox" value="<?php echo $starts_with; ?>" />
        </div>
        <label class="search-label">Search Keywords in:</label>
        <div>
            <select name="search[search_in]" id="search_in" class="demoInputBox">
                <option value="">Select Column</option>
                <option value="title" <?php if($search_in=="title") { echo "selected"; } ?>>Title</option>
                <option value="description" <?php if($search_in=="description") { echo "selected"; } ?>>Description</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="submit" name="go" class="btnSearch" value="Search">
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Please any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try echoing $sql and run that query in database

Comment: It echoed properly

Answer (score 0):

There are few different ways to do it. You can try using below mentioned ways -

1. `$query->fetch(SQLITE_ASSOC)`, this one is object oriented approach. Now you are following this approach, Change your code using this approach, hope it will work.
2. another way can be a procedural approach like this code `while ($entry = sqlite_fetch_array($query, SQLITE_ASSOC)) {`

Comment: Thanks but doesn't work, now i get `Call to undefined function sqlite_fetch_array()`.